# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor false/true a otro texto?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente tabla, la cual quiero que al mostrar los datos en vez de que aparezca false o true diga activo o inactivo.

```
 <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
  </td>
```

Intente agregando lo siguiente pero dice que ? no se puede utilizar en datos booleanos

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State ? "Activo" : "Inactivo")
</td>
```

Y este último no marca error pero me produce una excepción

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State != null && item.State.Value ? "Activo" : "Inactivo")
</td>
```

Comment: Qué tipo de dato es item.State ???

Comment: @Yussef es tipo bool, me dice que no se puede convertir

Comment: Es pero es `bool?  State` es decir nulleable?

Comment: En el modelo se generó de esta manera `public Nullable<bool> State { get; set; }` porque estoy usando database first

Comment: Probaste con la respuesta que te puse abajo?

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Nery si te sirvio la Respuesta de Yussef, puedes márcarla como  respuesta aceptada. ✓✓

Comment: Thnx @David081, desconocía que se podía hacer eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes poner

```
<td>
    @( (item.State!=null && item.State.Value) ? "Activo" : "Inactivo")
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando lo siguiente o algo parecido ("true") dependiendo que te sale como verdadero

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State.ToString()=="True" ? "Activo" : "Inactivo")
</td>
```

Comment: me sigue apareciendo la misma excepción: System.InvalidOperationException